# Why does the velocity of the two objects changes "gradually" after the collison?

Tags: kinematics

Theoretically, after a collision, the velocity of two objects must be changed by the law of conservation of momentum. But the velocity doesn't go straight from v(a) to v(b), it changes gradually. Why does it change **gradually**?

Comment: Who says it changes "gradually"? And what do you mean by "gradually"? In milliseconds? Seconds? Minutes?

Comment: forces may be very high but are not infinite.  forces on impact deform the objects- deformation is movement, which takes time.  you can model the masses as lots of springs (unbonded electrons repelling and bonded protons-electrons attracting)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say a car with a mass of, $m$, speed of $v$, and a bumper with spring with stiffness $K $ collide head-on with a wall.

It trades its kinetic energy gradually to the potential energy in the bumper springs over time, $t$

$$1/2mv^2=1/2 kx^2$$ remember our test crash is a perfect elastic collision

At any moment the deceleration is $a=kx/m$

Until the entire kinetic energy is spent and the cars stop. but now under the force of the spring, it accelerates back(in our example it survives the crash).

This is the basic idealized mechanism. However, we have no perfect elastic or perfect non-elastic collisions.

So we will have friction losses of kinetic energy and heat loss. Energy loss to ductile behavior of materials.

Answer (score 0):

I will interpret "gradually" as "continuously" or a velocity-time graph that has a defined slope and is differentiable at all points". As opposed to abruptly or a velocity-time graph with sharp corners, peaks, or vertical slopes.

Nothing happens instantly. Speed of light/causality and all that.

To change velocity abruptly (i.e. non-continuously) would require infinite acceleration which would require infinite force.

Even if you had infinite force you would not be able to accelerate real materials with infinite acceleration because applying an infinite force to real materials would cause them to disintegrate.

And even if you had infinite force and infinitely strong materials, you still could not achieve infinite acceleration unless the material was also infinitely rigid and immune to deformation.

Answer (score 0):

When collide, the car, as well as the object it runs into, deforms. The deformation dissipates the energy and impedes the velocity (forward motion), and to it reach the final state takes time, which is short but non-zero. Gradually means the deformation and decaying of velocity are carried out in a progressive manner rather than a sudden termination of motion. If you plot the graph of velocity vs deformation/energy, you should see a smooth concaving curve as opposed to a straight line dropping vertically to the zero axis.